# How would you test for both differences in mean AND differences in variance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose I wanted to test for a difference in BOTH the mean and variance, how would I go about constructing a test statistic for this purpose? 
 I suppose my null hypothesis would be that the mean and variance in one population are the same as the mean and variance in another, whilst the alternative hypothesis would be that they differ.

Comment: Hypotheses are put forward about populations, not about samples.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I've made the correction.

Comment: Isn't this effectively a duplicate of your other question, which has an answer? If this is different, could you clarify the difference?